# Changing component view based on route

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to show/hide an Angular component based on the route. If there's a simpler way, please let me know. I've tried many examples off stackoverflow but none seemed to work. Here is my code.

app.component.html:

```
<app-nav></app-nav> //shown on all pages
<app-home> </app-home> //shown only on home route ('/')
<app-contact> </app-contact> //shown only on contact route ('/')
```

nav.component.html:

```
<div class="contact-open" *ngIf="navStatus == 'contact'">
    <button (click)="contactPage()"> Contact </button>
</div>
```

nav.component.ts:

```
contactPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['/contact']);
 }
```

app-routing.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}
];
```

Ideally, once I select the button from nav html, it will change the route to /contact (which it does), but I want the app.component.html to only show the `<app-contact>`, and not the `<app-home>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the [RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet). You've already set up the correct components for your routes:

app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
];
```

So all you need to do is add the `router-outlet` placeholder to your app template:

app.component.html

```html
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

Once you've done this, Angular will render the `HomeComponent` where the `router-outlet` is when the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) is `/` and will render the `ContactComponent` where the `router-outlet` is when the `ActivatedRoute` is `/contact`.

You set the `ActivatedRoute` by typing the desired route in the URL bar of your browser, using the [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) directive on an element in a template, or using one of the methods on the [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) like you've done with `this.router.navigate(['contact'])`.

---

Here's what using the `RouterLink` directive would look like in your navigation:

nav.component.html

```html
<a routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
```

There are more examples (including more advanced use cases) in the [RouterLink documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description).